# remoteFunction won't work without render

Tags: grails

Here is a fragment of my javascript code:

```
 ${remoteFunction(controller: 'job', action: 'updateTimeStamp', update: 'randomString', params: '{timeStamp:timeStamp, sessionId:sessionId}')};
 var jobIsDone = ${remoteFunction(controller: 'job', action: 'jobIsDone', params: '{sessionId:sessionId}')};
```

The first line works as expected, and the second one gives me 404 exception. jobIsDone() method doesn't render anything. I couldn't find proper explanation of remoteFunction tag, but as far as I understood it can be used without rendering, am I mistaken?

Here are the controller methods:

```
def updateTimeStamp(){
    timeStampMap.putAt(params.sessionId, params.timeStamp)
    def randomString = bcvjobService.saySomething()
    render  "<p>${randomString}</p>"
}


def jobIsDone(){
    if (jobDone.get(params.sessionId)){
        return true
    }
    else return false
}
```

Comment: do you understand that it's AJAX call?

Comment: @Igor, thank you for the question, it really helped. Suppose I should delete mine)

Comment: :) `render` call is optional actually, if you have a view with same name. but it was unlikely that you've asked about this case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
def jobIsDone(){

    if (jobDone.get(params.sessionId)){
        response.sendError(200,"ok")
    }
    else {
 response.sendError(500,"error")
}

}
```

This will prevent the 404 not found. If you want that come back a true or false with a JSON for example is:

```
def jobIsDone(){
    def result = [error:true]
    if (jobDone.get(params.sessionId)){
        result.error = false
    }
    render result as JSON

}
```